# How to make 40x50 table in latex ? such that it is visible

Tags: tables

I have tried many options for table but is not coming inside the page, here is code

```latex
%time wise details
\begin{longtable}[c]{|l|@{}l@{}|@{}l@{}|@{}l@{}|@{}l@{}|@{}l@{}|@{}l@{}|@{}l@{}|@{}l@{}|@{}l@{}|@{}l@{}|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Sq\# & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 & 48 & 49 & 50 \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
%
\endhead
%
B1 &  &  & 0:00-0:26.4 &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:01-1:12\\ 1:14-1:29\\ 3:20-3:35\\ 3:38-3:56\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:08\\ 0:14-0:33\\ 1:30-1:40\\ 1:44-1:55\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:23-0:31\\ 0:38-0:55\\ 1:45-1:59\\ 2:04-2:20\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:45-1:13\\ 1:40-2:12\\ 5:00-5:34\\ 5:50-6:26\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:57-2:42\\ 8:22-8:55\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:25\\ 2:07-2:16\\ 2:31-2:42\\ 4:11-4:21\\ 4:37-4:59\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:14-0:19\\ 0:28-0:30\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:18-0:21\\ 0:56-1:02\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:11\\ 0:25-0:35\\ 4:41-4:53\\ 5:08-5:17\\ 9:03-9:13\end{tabular} &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:31\\ 3:49-4:12\\ 6:32-6:41\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:18\\ 2:01-2:19\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:35\\ 2:31-3:00\\ 3:23-3:54\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}07-3:20\\ 3:41-3:52\\ 8:21-8:34\\ 8:57-9:08\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:19\\ 1:33-1:49\\ 3:25-3:42\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:22\\ 0:40-0:47\\ 1:19-1:36\\ 1:49-1:58\\ 2:24-2:36\end{tabular} &  & 1:17-2:12 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:37-0:48\\ 4:48-5:00\end{tabular} & 1:22-1:40 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:32-0:47\\ 1:47-1:59\end{tabular} &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:06\\ 0:39-0:49.2\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:18\\ 0:37-0:50\\ 1:10-1:16\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:27-0:29\\ 0:49-0:51\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:53-1:04\\ 3:09-3:21\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:26-1:36\\ 5:38-5:47\end{tabular} &  &  &  & 0:21-0:25.1 \\ \hline
Cr1 &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:41-0:45\\ 1:12-1:18\\ 1:41-1:46\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:10\\ 0:55-1:01\\ 1:29-1:48\\ 2:21-2:30\\ 3:17-3:20\\ 3:56-4:11\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:33-0:50\\ 1:15-1:30\\ 1:55-2:11\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:23\\ 0:55-1:10\\ 1:33-1:45\\ 2:20-2:36\end{tabular} &  & 1:53-2:20 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:18-1:28\\ 2:27-2:37\end{tabular} &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:10\\ 0:17-0:45\\ 2:12-2:53\\ 4:30-5:00\\ 6:26-7:00\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:27-0:50\\ 6:09-6:21\\ 6:52-7:03\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:25-0:40\\ 1:53-2:07\\ 2:42-2:52\\ 3:58-4:11\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:14\\ 0:33-0:42\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:32-0:40\\ 0:50-0:53\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:54-2:20\\ 3:27-4:14\\ 4:21-4:50\\ 6:15-6:38\\ 6:58-7:30\\ 8:38-9:28\\ 9:30-10:06\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:35-0:37\\ 1:23-1:40\\ 2:11-2:22\\ 3:36-3:53\\ 4:35-4:41\\ 5:17-5:23\\ 5:53-6:08\\ 6:36-6:49\\ 7:53-8:10\\ 8:57-9:03\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:34-0:44\\ 1:11-1:24\\ 2:06-2:15\\ 2:19-2:46\\ 3:09-3:16\\ 3:30-3:43\\ 4:07-4:17\\ 4:46-5:00\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:17-0:21\\ 0:36-0:48\\ 1:01-1:09\\ 1:36-1:46\\ 2:15-2:27\\ 3:03-3:11\\ 3:15-3:39\\ 4:03-4:09\\ 4:26-4:36\\ 4:50-4:57\\ 5:21-5:32\\ 5:55-6:09\\ 6:51-7:01\\ 7:03-7:31\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:50-1:45\\ 2:12-2:18\\ 4:28-4:42\\ 5:10-5:16\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:18-0:24\\ 0:36-0:41\\ 1:56-2:01\\ 2:19-2:25\\ 2:37-2:42\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:35-1:15\\ 2:21-2:31\\ 3:54-4:35\\ 5:02-5:24\\ 5:33-5:57\\ 6:13-6:46\\ 8:25-8:39\\ 9:16-9:43\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:08-1:12\\ 1:31-1:41\\ 2:05-2:21\\ 2:43-3:07\\ 3:52-4:04\\ 4:32-4:57\\ 6:22-6:33\\ 7:02-7:08\\ 7:29-7:43\\ 8:06-8:21\\ 9:08-9:19\\ 9:44-10:06\end{tabular} &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:30-2:41\\ 2:52-3:20\\ 4:44-5:44\\ 5:54-6:15\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:15\\ 0:54-1:12\\ 1:50-1:53\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:19-0:33\\ 0:47-0:55\\ 0:58-1:15\\ 1:24-1:33\\ 1:49-2:02\\ 2:19-2:25\\ 2:40-2:44\\ 2:51-2:58\\ 3:02-3:09\\ 3:16-3:25\\ 3:42-3:55\\ 4:15-4:25\\ 4:42-4:50\\ 5:00-5:07\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:47-1:07\\ 1:58-2:15\end{tabular} & 0:26-0:45 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:01-1:17\\ 2:12-2:24\\ 3:22-3:31\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:10-0:19\\ 1:24-1:27\\ 2:03-2:11\\ 3:33-3:47\\ 3:55-4:02\\ 4:21-4:30\\ 5:37-5:39\\ 6:24-6:30\\ 7:44-7:56\\ 8:05-8:12\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:24-0:39\\ 1:11-1:22\\ 2:00-2:11\\ 3:23-4:05\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:09\\ 0:24-0:32\\ 0:47-0:52\\ 1:15-1:21\\ 1:26-1:27\\ 1:42-1:47\\ 1:59-2:03\\ 2:13-2:16\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:18-0:58\\ 1:12-1:24\end{tabular} &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:11-0:14\\ 0:38-0:40\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:14-0:27\\ 1:17-1:26\\ 1:35-1:39\\ 2:33-2:36\\ 2:43-2:45\\ 3:29-3:30\\ 4:21-4:24\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:00-1:06\\ 1:09-1:20\\ 2:12-2:14\\ 4:02-4:08\\ 5:14-5:20\\ 5:26-5:34\\ 6:25-6:27\\ 8:30-8:38\\ 9:28-9:35\\ 10:38-10:46\\ 11:40-11:46\\ 12:42-12:50\end{tabular} &  &  &  & 0:00-0:21 \\ \hline
K & 0:11-0:20 &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:09\\ 0:31-0:40\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:11-0:20\\ 0:45-0:53\\ 1:18-1:23\\ 1:46-1:48\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:19-0:53\\ 2:50-3:13\end{tabular} &  &  &  & 2:30-2:34 & 1:28-1:48 &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:42-0:45.6 & 0:00-0:13 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:26\\ 5:18-5:51\\ 6:38-6:49\end{tabular} &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:56-3:33\\ 5:49-6:22\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:06-1:23\\ 3:10-3:27\end{tabular} & 5:37-6:13 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:41-2:05\\ 6:33-7:02\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:12\\ 1:20-1:31\\ 2:15-2:29\end{tabular} & 5:19-5:28 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:19-0:26\\ 4:30-4:37\end{tabular} & 2:45-3:23 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1:35-1:46 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:12-0:27\\ 4:24-4:39\\ 9:47-10:03\\ 12:00-12:15\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Cr2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}3:09-3:42\\ 4:01-4:09\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:40-1:57\\ 2:42-3:10\\ 4:43-5:12\\ 8:05-8:22\\ 8:55-9:26\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:59-1:07\\ 1:44-1:48\\ 3:09-3:18\\ 3:47-3:53\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}3:05-3:13\\ 3:28-3:36\\ 7:26-7:35\\ 7:45-7:53\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:06-1:08\\ 1:48-1:55\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}3:31-4:14\\ 5:02-5:19\\ 8:11-8:28\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:31-0:37\\ 4:43-4:48\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:27-0:38\\ 0:52-0:53\\ 1:04-1:10\\ 1:13-1:17\\ 2:29-2:33\\ 2:45-2:52\\ 3:07-3:09\\ 3:21-3:29\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:20-1:26\\ 1:36-1:38\\ 1:40-1:48\\ 1:57-2:02\\ 2:08-2:12\\ 5:34-5:38\\ 5:47-5:49\\ 5:52-6:01\\ 6:10-6:14\\ 6:20-6:25\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
W1 &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:12-1:14\\ 3:35-3:38\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:08-0:14\\ 1:40-1:44\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:31-0:38\\ 1:59-2:04\end{tabular} &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:21-0:37\\ 0:51-0:58\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:13-1:40\\ 5:34-5:50\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}4:19-4:34\\ 10:41-10:55\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:40-0:51\\ 2:52-3:04\end{tabular} &  &  & 0:40-0:50 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}4:14-4:21\\ 9:28-9:30\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:11-0:25\\ 4:53-5:08\\ 9:13-9:17\end{tabular} & 1:52-2:06 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:48-1:01\\ 4:36-4:50\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:18-2:31\\ 5:16-5:27\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:24-0:36\\ 2:25-2:37\end{tabular} & 3:00-3:23 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:12-1:31\\ 7:08-7:29\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:33-0:47\\ 2:25-2:40\\ 4:50-5:00\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:22-0:40\\ 1:36-1:49\end{tabular} &  & 2:46-2:56 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:48-0:55\\ 5:00-5:07\end{tabular} & 1:40-2:00 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:09-0:24\\ 1:27-1:42\end{tabular} &  &  & 0:06-0:20 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:18-0:30\\ 0:50-1:01\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:14-0:27\\ 0:40-0:49\end{tabular} & 1:10-1:13 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:18\\ 0:52-1:03\\ 1:51-1:55\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:06-1:09\\ 5:20-5:26\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Cr3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 6:08-6:19 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:11-2:14\\ 2:44-2:50\\ 3:29-3:33\\ 6:30-6:34 \\ 6:59-7:05\\ 7:39-7:44\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}8:38-8:40\\ 8:46-8:50\\ 9:05-9:09\\ 9:21-9:28\\ 10:46-10:51\\ 11:00-11:04\\ 11:19-11:21\\ 11:33-11:40\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Di1 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:11\\ 0:34-0:36.2\end{tabular} &  &  & 0:09-0:21 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:11\\ 0:20-0:32\\ 0:53-1:03\\ 1:23-1:33\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:29\\ 2:34-2:57\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:10\\ 2:37-2:46\end{tabular} &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:10-0:17\\ 4:09-4:30\\ 7:00-7:19\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:51-0:59\\ 1:48-1:53\\ 3:04-3:09\\ 3:53-3:58\end{tabular} &  & 0:19-0:28 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:13-0:18\\ 1:02-1:04\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:26-0:54\\ 5:51-6:15\end{tabular} &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:31-0:37\\ 2:31-2:56\\ 3:33-3:49\\ 4:12-4:20\\ 5:27-5:49\\ 6:22-6:32\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:41-0:43\\ 0:59-1:06\\ 1:23-1:32\\ 1:49-1:56\\ 3:01-3:10\\ 3:27-3:33\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:52-2:21\\ 6:46-7:17\\ 7:35-8:25\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:19-0:40\\ 0:53-1:00\\ 6:09-6:12\\ 9:24-9:44\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:53-1:25\\ 3:36-4:11\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:20-0:34\\ 0:38-1:06\\ 1:11-1:30\end{tabular} &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}4:25-4:42\\ 5:07-5:11\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:12-0:26\\ 0:45-1:06\\ 1:08-1:20\\ 1:37-1:48\\ 1:55-2:15\\ 2:29-2:34\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:17\\ 0:42-1:01\\ 8:54-9:23\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:26-0:31\\ 1:07-1:11\\ 4:37-4:43\\ 5:19-5:24\end{tabular} & 2:33-2:45 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:38-0:52\\ 2:52-3:07\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:22-0:24\\ 1:05-1:22\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:12\\ 4:11-4:24\\ 9:38-9:47\\ 11:51-12:00\\ 12:15-12:20\end{tabular} & 0:00-0:06 & 0:00-0:06.4 &  &  \\ \hline
W2 &  &  &  &  &  & 2:07-2:10 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:00-1:10\\ 2:19-2:23\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:18-1:28\\ 2:42-2:46\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  & 2:53-3:09 &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:16-2:31\\ 4:21-4:37\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:01-1:15\\ 5:36-5:46\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:53-3:03\\ 6:38-6:51\end{tabular} &  &  & 4:35-5:02 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:21-2:43\\ 7:43-8:06\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:15-1:24\\ 3:09-3:16\end{tabular} &  &  & 6:44-7:04 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:02-1:07 \\ 5:15-5:19\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:47-1:58\\ 3:44-3:48\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:38-1:40\\ 5:49-5:52\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Di2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}4:50-5:18\\ 6:49-6:58\\ 10:06-10:22\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  & 8:39-9:08 & 4:04-4:19 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:25-1:52\\ 2:24-2:44\\ 4:11-4:35\\ 5:00-5:21\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}5:51-6:08\\ 7:33-7:40\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:27-1:40\\ 1:54-2:03\\ 5:39-5:59\\ 6:15-6:24\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:24-0:45\\ 1:22-1:30\end{tabular} &  & 0:06-0:09.4 &  &  &  \\ \hline
W3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:51-2:04\\ 6:18-6:28\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  & 5:24-5:33 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}3:20-3:41\\ 8:34-8:57\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 7:21-7:33 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:21-2:36\\ 6:41-6:52\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:58-2:10\\ 3:48-4:01\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}3:22-3:27\\ 3:43-3:46\\ 7:34-7:40\\ 7:56-8:01\\ 13:27-13:32\\ 13:45-13:52\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
B2 &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:48-2:07\\ 2:07-2:21\\ 4:11-4:33\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:50-1:00\\ 1:10-1:15\\ 2:11-2:19\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:10-1:18\\ 1:28-1:33\\ 2:36-2:42\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}3:10-4:10\\ 9:26-10:26\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:37-1:01\\ 1:15-1:23\\ 5:23-5:36\\ 5:46-5:53\end{tabular} &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:45-2:12\\ 4:42-5:10\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:32-1:49\\ 3:33-3:37\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:02-2:19\\ 3:55-4:15\end{tabular} &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:24-2:46\\ 2:56-3:22\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:14-2:21\\ 2:36-2:44\\ 6:34-6:41\\ 6:52-6:59\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:39-1:47\\ 2:10-2:16\\ 2:26-2:29\\ 3:30-3:44\\ 4:01-4:07\\ 4:17-4:21\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:48-1:57\\ 6:01-6:10\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
W4 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:27-2:32\\ 2:42-2:50\\ 6:54-6:59\\ 7:07-7:10\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}3:05-3:13 \\ 7:17-7:24\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}3:27-3:37\\ 7:40-7:50\\ 13:32-13:42\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
B3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}3:13-3:28\\ 7:35-7:45\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 6:19-6:44 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:50-3:05\\ 3:13-3:29\\ 7:05-7:17\\ 7:24-7:39\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:39-2:50\\ 2:57-3:01\\ 3:46-3:53\\ 7:04-7:15\\ 7:20-7:25\\ 8:01-8:07\\ 12:58-13:08\\ 13:16-13:23\\ 13:52-13:55\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Dw1 & 0:25-0:34 &  &  & 0:21-0:27 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:32-0:38\\ 1:03-1:09\\ 1:33-1:38\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:15-0:19\\ 2:38-2:50\end{tabular} &  &  &  & 00:51-1:25 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:48-1:04\\ 2:10-2:20\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:17-0:21\\ 0:37-0:39\\ 0:58-1:05\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:05-0:08\\ 0:34-0:37.3\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:52-1:40\\ 5:12-6:09\\ 7:03-8:05\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:20-2:53\\ 3:10-3:27\\ 7:30-7:48\\ 8:15-8:38\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:34\\ 3:43-4:07\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:09-1:36\\ 4:57-5:21\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:37-0:50\\ 4:20-4:28\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:43-0:59\\ 2:42-3:01\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:00-1:08\\ 5:33-5:53\\ 6:12-6:22\end{tabular} &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:09-1:30\\ 4:23-4:44\\ 6:32-6:54\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}5:28-5:51\\ 7:40-8:11\end{tabular} &  & 2:20-2:33 &  &  &  & 0:23-0:27 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:33-0:37\\ 1:04-1:10\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:06\\ 0:29-0:34\\ 0:51-0:54\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:18-0:22\\ 0:45-0:52\\ 1:03-1:05\\ 1:46-1:51\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:27-0:35\\ 4:08-4:11\\ 4:39-4:46\\ 9:35-9:38\\ 10:03-10:11\\ 11:46-11:51\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
B4 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}9:09-9:21\\ 11:21-11:33\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
W5 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:32-2:42\\ 6:59-7:07\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}3:47-3:55\\ 7:56-8:05\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}3:37-3:43\\ 7:50-7:56\\ 13:42-13:45\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
St1 & 0:20-0:25 &  &  & 0:27-0:31 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:38-0:41\\ 1:09-1:12\\ 1:38-1:41\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:10-0:15\\ 0:51-0:55\\ 2:30-2:38\\ 3:10-3:17\end{tabular} &  &  &  & 2:20-2:30 & 0:40-0:48 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:10\\ 0:42-0:46\\ 1:07-1:09\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 2:15-2:19 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}3:11-3:15\\ 7:01-7:03\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:34-0:53\\ 3:18-3:36\end{tabular} & 0:00-0:20 &  &  &  &  & 1:31-1:37 &  &  & 2:11-2:20 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1:30-1:35 &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
W6 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}8:50-9:05\\ 11:04-11:19\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Dw2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:53-3:10\\ 7:48-8:15\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:14-2:39\\ 3:53-4:02\\ 6:27-7:04\\ 8:07-8:30\\ 12:50-12:58\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
St2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 2:56-3:01 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}3:49-3:54\\ 7:41-7:46\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:34-0:38\\ 1:06-1:11\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
O &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:47-0:51 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:32-0:40\\ 2:08-2:10\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:30-0:33 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:21-0:32\\ 0:53-0:56\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:40-1:51\\ 2:04-2:11\\ 6:08-6:18\\ 6:28-6:36\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  & 9:08-9:16 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}4:19-4:32\\ 9:19-9:24\end{tabular} &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:25-0:57\\ 3:42-4:06\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:17-0:42\\ 8:28-8:54\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:41-1:54\\ 5:59-6:15\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  & 0:20-0:23 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:30-0:33\\ 1:01-1:04\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:34-0:38\\ 0:54-0:56.3\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  & 0:00-0:07.2 &  \\ \hline
T &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:27\\ 6:21-6:52\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:34\\ 2:44-3:18\\ 5:21-5:24\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:25\\ 0:57-1:09\\ 3:20-3:42\\ 4:06-4:23\\ 6:16-6:32\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:11-1:24\\ 5:24-5:37\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:06-0:11 &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:35-0:50\\ 4:46-5:04\\ 10:11-10:28\\ 12:20-12:33\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
La &  & 0:00-0:49 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:46\\ 0:58-2:24\\ 2:36-3:16\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  & 4:34-4:43 &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:13-1:27\\ 1:50-3:47\\ 4:01-4:35\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:15-0:54 \\ 1:12-1:50\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:27-0:39 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Li &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:46-0:58\\ 2:24-2:36\end{tabular} & 0:29-0:47 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:10-0:32 \\ 1:48-2:08\end{tabular} & 0:46-0:51 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1:15-1:52 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:19\\ 4:57-5:33\\ 10:06-10:46\end{tabular} &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:41-2:52\\ 5:44-5:54\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:50-1:00\\ 5:04-5:14\\ 10:28-10:38\\ 12:33-12:42\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Ch &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:00-3:48 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
De1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:10-0:17\\ 0:39-0:42\\ 1:05-1:07\end{tabular} & 0:08-0:15 &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}4:10-4:19\\ 10:26-10:41\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:22-2:27\\ 2:58-3:05\\ 6:49-6:54\\ 7:21-7:26\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:55-0:58\\ 2:44-2:51\end{tabular} &  &  & 7:04-7:21 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:55-1:02\\ 5:07-5:15\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:16-2:26\\ 4:07-4:17\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:50-2:57\\ 7:15-7:20\\ 13:08-13:16\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
P1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1:25-1:53 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:04-1:18\\ 2:10-2:27\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:05\\ 0:31-0:34\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:52-1:15\\ 2:03-2:13\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
De2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:50-2:58\\ 7:10-7:21\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 2:58-3:02 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}3:01-3:22\\ 7:25-7:34\\ 13:23-13:27\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
P2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:21-1:26\\ 2:16-2:41\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
De3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}8:40-8:46\\ 10:51-11:00\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
E1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:15-0:31 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:44-1:11\\ 4:17-4:46\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:21-0:36\\ 4:09-4:26\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:52-2:24\\ 4:35-5:00\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:39-1:11 &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:18\\ 1:24-1:47\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Cn &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 4:14-5:02 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:10\\ 4:02-4:21\\ 8:12-8:25\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
E2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:24-1:52\\ 5:00-5:25\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:46-2:15\\ 5:32-5:55\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:58-1:12 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
SR &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3:42-4:01 &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:07-1:44\\ 3:18-3:47\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}3:53-4:35\\ 8:10-8:57\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:46-2:56\\ 3:01-3:09\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:17\\ 3:39-3:49\\ 3:54-4:03\\ 7:31-7:41\\ 7:46-7:52\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
E3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3:16-3:30 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:27-2:53\\ 6:09-6:38\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Sl &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 7:17-7:35 & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:40-0:53\\ 5:53-6:09\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Sa &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1:07-1:19 \\ 2:15-2:24\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
SP &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:13\\ 1:27-1:50\\ 3:47-4:01\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Ly &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:24\\ 4:05-4:21\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  &  &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}0:00-0:14\\ 1:26-1:35\\ 2:36-2:43\\ 4:24-4:27\end{tabular} &  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}2:02-2:08 \\ 6:14-6:20\end{tabular} &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
\caption{Time Spent in Every Room}
\label{tab:my-table}\\
\end{longtable}
}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

I have also tried it in landscape mode (whose results are worst)

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE, could you make your script compilable? and could you give us detail on what is your paper size etc.,?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages (see also: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))

Comment: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144) might be interesting.

Comment: my paper size is A4

Comment: I have used following packages

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage{tabularx}

Comment: You can't put an elephant into lady suitcase ... your table will have so tiny text that it will not be usable.

Comment: @Zarko any suggestions

Comment: @UsamaMudassar, split your table on subtables or reconsider again, if you really need this table.

Comment: ok, I would see that option @Zarko

Comment: @Zarko: Great analogy. I'll definitely have to keep this in mind.

Comment: If you have available a printer that prints landscape A3 paper, 40x50 should be possible, in particular since OP use long table.

Comment: @Sveinung OP has not yet given their complete example, so its a generous assumption to make and the OP already mentioned that preference of A4 ;)

Comment: RE: @Zarko 's subtable suggestion, the current table appears to be rather sparse.  One could hyperlink the subtables back to a main table.

Comment: oh we can do that in latex ? can you kindly tell me its process @JohnKormylo ?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507771/how-to-link-subtables-to-a-tabular

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The three examples below show you that you probably need A2 paper to print a readable table with your content. You may set up LaTeX to write on such paper size, and then print pieces at A4 paper and glue them to a A2 sheet.

**A4 landscape - `fontsize=4pt`**

Here you see how your table will be using margins and font size that enable you to squeese your data in between the cell borders. I removed all the nested tabulars from your code. They are confusing and unnecessary.

Font size is 4 pt on 20 per cent leading, in daily life unreadable. You probably have to print this using a high quality, high resolution printer on high quality paper. I loaded [lmodern](https://ctan.org/pkg/lmodern) to have scalable fonts, and reduced the font to 4pt with . There are still some overfull hboxes, but they are less than 0.2pt too wide, so I do not use time to get rid of them, given my conclusion.

The left and right margins are set to 0.3 cm, which is minimum for most laser printers. Professional printers may use 0 pt.

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2cm, bottom=3cm, left=0.3cm, right=0.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable, array}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.2pt}
\newcolumntype{N}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr((\textwidth/51)-(2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth))}}

\begin{document}

%time wise details
\fontsize{4}{4.8}\selectfont
\begin{longtable}[c]{*{51}{N}|}
\hline
\textbf Sq\# & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 & 48 & 49 & 50 \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption{Time Spent in Every Room\label{tab:my-table}}\\
\hline
\textbf Sq\# & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 & 48 & 49 & 50 \\ \hline
\endhead

B1 &  &  & 0:00-0:26.4 &  &  & 1:01-1:12 1:14-1:29 3:20-3:35 3:38-3:56 & 0:00-0:08 0:14-0:33 1:30-1:40 1:44-1:55 & 0:23-0:31 0:38-0:55 1:45-1:59 2:04-2:20 &  &  &  &  &  & 0:45-1:13 1:40-2:12 5:00-5:34 5:50-6:26 & 1:57-2:42 8:22-8:55 & 0:00-0:25 2:07-2:16 2:31-2:42 4:11-4:21 4:37-4:59 &  & 0:14-0:19 0:28-0:30 & 0:18-0:21 0:56-1:02 &  & 0:00-0:11 0:25-0:35 4:41-4:53 5:08-5:17 9:03-9:13 &  &  & 0:00-0:31 3:49-4:12 6:32-6:41 & 0:00-0:18 2:01-2:19 & 0:00-0:35 2:31-3:00 3:23-3:54 & 07-3:20 3:41-3:52 8:21-8:34 8:57-9:08 &  &  &  &  & 0:00-0:19 1:33-1:49 3:25-3:42 & 0:00-0:22 0:40-0:47 1:19-1:36 1:49-1:58 2:24-2:36 &  & 1:17-2:12 & 0:37-0:48 4:48-5:00 & 1:22-1:40 & 0:32-0:47 1:47-1:59 &  &  & 0:00-0:06 0:39-0:49.2 & 0:00-0:18 0:37-0:50 1:10-1:16 & 0:27-0:29 0:49-0:51 & 0:53-1:04 3:09-3:21 &  & 1:26-1:36 5:38-5:47 &  &  &  & 0:21-0:25.1  \\ \hline
Cr1 &  &  &  &  & 0:41-0:45 1:12-1:18 1:41-1:46 & 0:00-0:10 0:55-1:01 1:29-1:48 2:21-2:30 3:17-3:20 3:56-4:11 & 0:33-0:50 1:15-1:30 1:55-2:11 & 0:00-0:23 0:55-1:10 1:33-1:45 2:20-2:36 &  & 1:53-2:20 & 1:18-1:28 2:27-2:37 &  &  & 0:00-0:10 0:17-0:45 2:12-2:53 4:30-5:00 6:26-7:00 & 0:27-0:50 6:09-6:21 6:52-7:03 & 0:25-0:40 1:53-2:07 2:42-2:52 3:58-4:11 &  & 0:00-0:14 0:33-0:42 & 0:32-0:40 0:50-0:53 & 0:54-2:20 3:27-4:14 4:21-4:50 6:15-6:38 6:58-7:30 8:38-9:28 9:30-10:06 & 0:35-0:37 1:23-1:40 2:11-2:22 3:36-3:53 4:35-4:41 5:17-5:23 5:53-6:08 6:36-6:49 7:53-8:10 8:57-9:03 & 0:34-0:44 1:11-1:24 2:06-2:15 2:19-2:46 3:09-3:16 3:30-3:43 4:07-4:17 4:46-5:00 & 0:17-0:21 0:36-0:48 1:01-1:09 1:36-1:46 2:15-2:27 3:03-3:11 3:15-3:39 4:03-4:09 4:26-4:36 4:50-4:57 5:21-5:32 5:55-6:09 6:51-7:01 7:03-7:31 & 0:50-1:45 2:12-2:18 4:28-4:42 5:10-5:16 & 0:18-0:24 0:36-0:41 1:56-2:01 2:19-2:25 2:37-2:42 & 0:35-1:15 2:21-2:31 3:54-4:35 5:02-5:24 5:33-5:57 6:13-6:46 8:25-8:39 9:16-9:43 & 1:08-1:12 1:31-1:41 2:05-2:21 2:43-3:07 3:52-4:04 4:32-4:57 6:22-6:33 7:02-7:08 7:29-7:43 8:06-8:21 9:08-9:19 9:44-10:06 &  &  & 1:30-2:41 2:52-3:20 4:44-5:44 5:54-6:15 & 0:00-0:15 0:54-1:12 1:50-1:53 & 0:19-0:33 0:47-0:55 0:58-1:15 1:24-1:33 1:49-2:02 2:19-2:25 2:40-2:44 2:51-2:58 3:02-3:09 3:16-3:25 3:42-3:55 4:15-4:25 4:42-4:50 5:00-5:07 & 0:47-1:07 1:58-2:15 & 0:26-0:45 & 1:01-1:17 2:12-2:24 3:22-3:31 & 0:10-0:19 1:24-1:27 2:03-2:11 3:33-3:47 3:55-4:02 4:21-4:30 5:37-5:39 6:24-6:30 7:44-7:56 8:05-8:12 & 0:24-0:39 1:11-1:22 2:00-2:11 3:23-4:05 & 0:00-0:09 0:24-0:32 0:47-0:52 1:15-1:21 1:26-1:27 1:42-1:47 1:59-2:03 2:13-2:16 & 0:18-0:58 1:12-1:24 &  &  &  & 0:11-0:14 0:38-0:40 & 0:14-0:27 1:17-1:26 1:35-1:39 2:33-2:36 2:43-2:45 3:29-3:30 4:21-4:24 &  & 1:00-1:06 1:09-1:20 2:12-2:14 4:02-4:08 5:14-5:20 5:26-5:34 6:25-6:27 8:30-8:38 9:28-9:35 10:38-10:46 11:40-11:46 12:42-12:50 &  &  &  & 0:00-0:21  \\ \hline
K & 0:11-0:20 &  &  & 0:00-0:09 0:31-0:40 & 0:11-0:20 0:45-0:53 1:18-1:23 1:46-1:48 & 0:19-0:53 2:50-3:13 &  &  &  & 2:30-2:34 & 1:28-1:48 &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:42-0:45.6 & 0:00-0:13 & 0:00-0:26 5:18-5:51 6:38-6:49 &  &  &  & 2:56-3:33 5:49-6:22 & 1:06-1:23 3:10-3:27 & 5:37-6:13 & 1:41-2:05 6:33-7:02 &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:00-0:12 1:20-1:31 2:15-2:29 & 5:19-5:28 & 0:19-0:26 4:30-4:37 & 2:45-3:23 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1:35-1:46 & 0:12-0:27 4:24-4:39 9:47-10:03 12:00-12:15 &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
Cr2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3:09-3:42 4:01-4:09 & 1:40-1:57 2:42-3:10 4:43-5:12 8:05-8:22 8:55-9:26 & 0:59-1:07 1:44-1:48 3:09-3:18 3:47-3:53 &  &  &  &  & 3:05-3:13 3:28-3:36 7:26-7:35 7:45-7:53 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1:06-1:08 1:48-1:55 & 3:31-4:14 5:02-5:19 8:11-8:28 & 0:31-0:37 4:43-4:48 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:27-0:38 0:52-0:53 1:04-1:10 1:13-1:17 2:29-2:33 2:45-2:52 3:07-3:09 3:21-3:29 &  & 1:20-1:26 1:36-1:38 1:40-1:48 1:57-2:02 2:08-2:12 5:34-5:38 5:47-5:49 5:52-6:01 6:10-6:14 6:20-6:25 &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
W1 &  &  &  &  &  & 1:12-1:14 3:35-3:38 & 0:08-0:14 1:40-1:44 & 0:31-0:38 1:59-2:04 &  &  &  & 0:21-0:37 0:51-0:58 &  & 1:13-1:40 5:34-5:50 & 4:19-4:34 10:41-10:55 & 0:40-0:51 2:52-3:04 &  &  & 0:40-0:50 & 4:14-4:21 9:28-9:30 & 0:11-0:25 4:53-5:08 9:13-9:17 & 1:52-2:06 & 0:48-1:01 4:36-4:50 & 2:18-2:31 5:16-5:27 & 0:24-0:36 2:25-2:37 & 3:00-3:23 & 1:12-1:31 7:08-7:29 &  &  &  &  & 0:33-0:47 2:25-2:40 4:50-5:00 & 0:22-0:40 1:36-1:49 &  & 2:46-2:56 & 0:48-0:55 5:00-5:07 & 1:40-2:00 & 0:09-0:24 1:27-1:42 &  &  & 0:06-0:20 & 0:18-0:30 0:50-1:01 & 0:14-0:27 0:40-0:49 & 1:10-1:13 & 0:00-0:18 0:52-1:03 1:51-1:55 & 1:06-1:09 5:20-5:26 &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
Cr3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 6:08-6:19 & 2:11-2:14 2:44-2:50 3:29-3:33 6:30-6:34  6:59-7:05 7:39-7:44 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 8:38-8:40 8:46-8:50 9:05-9:09 9:21-9:28 10:46-10:51 11:00-11:04 11:19-11:21 11:33-11:40 &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
Di1 & 0:00-0:11 0:34-0:36.2 &  &  & 0:09-0:21 & 0:00-0:11 0:20-0:32 0:53-1:03 1:23-1:33 &  &  &  &  & 0:00-0:29 2:34-2:57 & 0:00-0:10 2:37-2:46 &  &  & 0:10-0:17 4:09-4:30 7:00-7:19 &  & 0:51-0:59 1:48-1:53 3:04-3:09 3:53-3:58 &  & 0:19-0:28 & 0:13-0:18 1:02-1:04 & 0:26-0:54 5:51-6:15 &  &  &  & 0:31-0:37 2:31-2:56 3:33-3:49 4:12-4:20 5:27-5:49 6:22-6:32 & 0:41-0:43 0:59-1:06 1:23-1:32 1:49-1:56 3:01-3:10 3:27-3:33 & 1:52-2:21 6:46-7:17 7:35-8:25 & 0:19-0:40 0:53-1:00 6:09-6:12 9:24-9:44 & 0:53-1:25 3:36-4:11 & 0:20-0:34 0:38-1:06 1:11-1:30 &  &  & 4:25-4:42 5:07-5:11 &  & 0:12-0:26 0:45-1:06 1:08-1:20 1:37-1:48 1:55-2:15 2:29-2:34 & 0:00-0:17 0:42-1:01 8:54-9:23 & 0:26-0:31 1:07-1:11 4:37-4:43 5:19-5:24 & 2:33-2:45 &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:38-0:52 2:52-3:07 & 0:22-0:24 1:05-1:22 & 0:00-0:12 4:11-4:24 9:38-9:47 11:51-12:00 12:15-12:20 & 0:00-0:06 & 0:00-0:06.4 &  &   \\ \hline
W2 &  &  &  &  &  & 2:07-2:10 & 1:00-1:10 2:19-2:23 & 1:18-1:28 2:42-2:46 &  &  &  &  &  & 2:53-3:09 &  & 2:16-2:31 4:21-4:37 &  &  &  &  & 1:01-1:15 5:36-5:46 &  & 2:53-3:03 6:38-6:51 &  &  & 4:35-5:02 & 2:21-2:43 7:43-8:06 &  &  &  &  & 1:15-1:24 3:09-3:16 &  &  & 6:44-7:04 & 1:02-1:07  5:15-5:19 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1:47-1:58 3:44-3:48 &  & 1:38-1:40 5:49-5:52 &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
Di2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 4:50-5:18 6:49-6:58 10:06-10:22 &  &  &  &  &  & 8:39-9:08 & 4:04-4:19 & 1:25-1:52 2:24-2:44 4:11-4:35 5:00-5:21 &  &  &  &  &  &  & 5:51-6:08 7:33-7:40 & 1:27-1:40 1:54-2:03 5:39-5:59 6:15-6:24 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:24-0:45 1:22-1:30 &  & 0:06-0:09.4 &  &  &   \\ \hline
W3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1:51-2:04 6:18-6:28 &  &  &  &  & 5:24-5:33 & 3:20-3:41 8:34-8:57 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 7:21-7:33 & 2:21-2:36 6:41-6:52 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1:58-2:10 3:48-4:01 &  & 3:22-3:27 3:43-3:46 7:34-7:40 7:56-8:01 13:27-13:32 13:45-13:52 &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
B2 &  &  &  &  &  & 1:48-2:07 2:07-2:21 4:11-4:33 & 0:50-1:00 1:10-1:15 2:11-2:19 & 1:10-1:18 1:28-1:33 2:36-2:42 &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3:10-4:10 9:26-10:26 &  &  &  &  &  & 0:37-1:01 1:15-1:23 5:23-5:36 5:46-5:53 &  &  & 1:45-2:12 4:42-5:10 & 1:32-1:49 3:33-3:37 &  &  &  &  &  &  & 2:02-2:19 3:55-4:15 &  &  & 2:24-2:46 2:56-3:22 & 2:14-2:21 2:36-2:44 6:34-6:41 6:52-6:59 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1:39-1:47 2:10-2:16 2:26-2:29 3:30-3:44 4:01-4:07 4:17-4:21 &  & 1:48-1:57 6:01-6:10 &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
W4 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 2:27-2:32 2:42-2:50 6:54-6:59 7:07-7:10 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3:05-3:13  7:17-7:24 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3:27-3:37 7:40-7:50 13:32-13:42 &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
B3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3:13-3:28 7:35-7:45 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 6:19-6:44 & 2:50-3:05 3:13-3:29 7:05-7:17 7:24-7:39 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 2:39-2:50 2:57-3:01 3:46-3:53 7:04-7:15 7:20-7:25 8:01-8:07 12:58-13:08 13:16-13:23 13:52-13:55 &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
Dw1 & 0:25-0:34 &  &  & 0:21-0:27 & 0:32-0:38 1:03-1:09 1:33-1:38 & 0:15-0:19 2:38-2:50 &  &  &  & 00:51-1:25 & 0:48-1:04 2:10-2:20 & 0:17-0:21 0:37-0:39 0:58-1:05 & 0:05-0:08 0:34-0:37.3 &  & 0:52-1:40 5:12-6:09 7:03-8:05 &  &  &  &  & 2:20-2:53 3:10-3:27 7:30-7:48 8:15-8:38 &  & 0:00-0:34 3:43-4:07 & 1:09-1:36 4:57-5:21 & 0:37-0:50 4:20-4:28 & 0:43-0:59 2:42-3:01 &  & 1:00-1:08 5:33-5:53 6:12-6:22 &  &  & 1:09-1:30 4:23-4:44 6:32-6:54 &  &  &  &  & 5:28-5:51 7:40-8:11 &  & 2:20-2:33 &  &  &  & 0:23-0:27 & 0:33-0:37 1:04-1:10 & 0:00-0:06 0:29-0:34 0:51-0:54 &  & 0:18-0:22 0:45-0:52 1:03-1:05 1:46-1:51 & 0:27-0:35 4:08-4:11 4:39-4:46 9:35-9:38 10:03-10:11 11:46-11:51 &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
B4 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 9:09-9:21 11:21-11:33 &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
W5 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 2:32-2:42 6:59-7:07 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3:47-3:55 7:56-8:05 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3:37-3:43 7:50-7:56 13:42-13:45 &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
St1 & 0:20-0:25 &  &  & 0:27-0:31 & 0:38-0:41 1:09-1:12 1:38-1:41 & 0:10-0:15 0:51-0:55 2:30-2:38 3:10-3:17 &  &  &  & 2:20-2:30 & 0:40-0:48 & 0:00-0:10 0:42-0:46 1:07-1:09 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 2:15-2:19 & 3:11-3:15 7:01-7:03 &  &  &  &  & 0:34-0:53 3:18-3:36 & 0:00-0:20 &  &  &  &  & 1:31-1:37 &  &  & 2:11-2:20 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1:30-1:35 &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
W6 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 8:50-9:05 11:04-11:19 &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
Dw2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 2:53-3:10 7:48-8:15 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 2:14-2:39 3:53-4:02 6:27-7:04 8:07-8:30 12:50-12:58 &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
St2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 2:56-3:01 & 3:49-3:54 7:41-7:46 &  &  &  &  &  & 0:34-0:38 1:06-1:11 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
O &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:47-0:51 & 0:32-0:40 2:08-2:10 &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:30-0:33 & 0:21-0:32 0:53-0:56 &  & 1:40-1:51 2:04-2:11 6:08-6:18 6:28-6:36 &  &  &  &  & 9:08-9:16 & 4:19-4:32 9:19-9:24 &  &  & 0:25-0:57 3:42-4:06 &  &  &  &  & 0:17-0:42 8:28-8:54 & 1:41-1:54 5:59-6:15 &  &  &  &  & 0:20-0:23 & 0:30-0:33 1:01-1:04 & 0:34-0:38 0:54-0:56.3 &  &  &  &  &  & 0:00-0:07.2 &   \\ \hline
T &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:00-0:27 6:21-6:52 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:00-0:34 2:44-3:18 5:21-5:24 &  & 0:00-0:25 0:57-1:09 3:20-3:42 4:06-4:23 6:16-6:32 &  &  &  &  &  & 1:11-1:24 5:24-5:37 &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:06-0:11 &  &  & 0:35-0:50 4:46-5:04 10:11-10:28 12:20-12:33 &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
La &  & 0:00-0:49 &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:00-0:46 0:58-2:24 2:36-3:16 &  &  &  &  &  & 4:34-4:43 &  & 0:13-1:27 1:50-3:47 4:01-4:35 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:15-0:54  1:12-1:50 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:27-0:39 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
Li &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:46-0:58 2:24-2:36 & 0:29-0:47 & 0:10-0:32  1:48-2:08 & 0:46-0:51 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1:15-1:52 & 0:00-0:19 4:57-5:33 10:06-10:46 &  &  & 2:41-2:52 5:44-5:54 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:50-1:00 5:04-5:14 10:28-10:38 12:33-12:42 &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
Ch &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:00-3:48 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
De1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:10-0:17 0:39-0:42 1:05-1:07 & 0:08-0:15 &  & 4:10-4:19 10:26-10:41 &  &  &  &  &  & 2:22-2:27 2:58-3:05 6:49-6:54 7:21-7:26 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:55-0:58 2:44-2:51 &  &  & 7:04-7:21 & 0:55-1:02 5:07-5:15 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 2:16-2:26 4:07-4:17 &  & 2:50-2:57 7:15-7:20 13:08-13:16 &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
P1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1:25-1:53 & 1:04-1:18 2:10-2:27 &  & 0:00-0:05 0:31-0:34 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:52-1:15 2:03-2:13 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
De2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 2:50-2:58 7:10-7:21 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 2:58-3:02 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3:01-3:22 7:25-7:34 13:23-13:27 &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
P2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1:21-1:26 2:16-2:41 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
De3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 8:40-8:46 10:51-11:00 &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
E1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:15-0:31 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:44-1:11 4:17-4:46 & 0:21-0:36 4:09-4:26 &  &  &  &  & 1:52-2:24 4:35-5:00 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:39-1:11 &  & 0:00-0:18 1:24-1:47 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
Cn &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 4:14-5:02 & 0:00-0:10 4:02-4:21 8:12-8:25 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
E2 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1:24-1:52 5:00-5:25 & 1:46-2:15 5:32-5:55 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:58-1:12 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
SR &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3:42-4:01 &  & 1:07-1:44 3:18-3:47 &  &  &  &  & 3:53-4:35 8:10-8:57 & 2:46-2:56 3:01-3:09 & 0:00-0:17 3:39-3:49 3:54-4:03 7:31-7:41 7:46-7:52 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
E3 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 3:16-3:30 & 2:27-2:53 6:09-6:38 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
Sl &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 7:17-7:35 & 0:40-0:53 5:53-6:09 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
Sa &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 1:07-1:19  2:15-2:24 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
SP &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:00-0:13 1:27-1:50 3:47-4:01 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ \hline
Ly &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:00-0:24 4:05-4:21 &  &  &  &  &  &  & 0:00-0:14 1:26-1:35 2:36-2:43 4:24-4:27 &  & 2:02-2:08  6:14-6:20 &  &  &  &   \\ \hline

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

**A3 landscape**

Here you are in A3 landscape, with yor data in the table. I have not updated the source code because it is so much data that I hit the limit for answers. I had to reduce the font size to `\footnotesize`, so the table is not very readable:

[image]

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[a3paper, top=2cm, bottom=3cm, left=0.3cm, right=0.3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable, array}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.2pt}
\newcolumntype{N}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr((\textwidth/51)-(2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth))}}

\begin{document}

%time wise details
\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}[c]{*{51}{N}|}
\hline

\textbf Sq\# & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 & 48 & 49 & 50 \\ \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption{Time Spent in Every Room\label{tab:my-table}}\\
\textbf Sq\# & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20 & 21 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36 & 37 & 38 & 39 & 40 & 41 & 42 & 43 & 44 & 45 & 46 & 47 & 48 & 49 & 50 \\ \hline

\endhead

%[the data is the same as between \endhead and \end{longtable} above]

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

**A4 landscape**

Here you see your table set on A4 paper with font size `tiny`, which is `5pt`. I reduced `\tabcolsep` to near nothing, and the rule width to 0.2 pt. Still, your data overflowed the cells (see last row).

Conclusion: Using A4, you table will be useless.

[image]

Comment: And where is magnifying glass for readers (of this table) ;-)

Comment: But OP has in cells a numbers like `1:48-2:077`, over the thumb, the font size will have to be smaller than `\tiny` ... with wish, that table should be on one A4 page :-(

Comment: I have no daubs that technically it is possible to put this table in one page. But who will read it is another question,  as you said at second example in your example. So, at such monstrous tables tables you must first ask yourself what the purpose of such a table is.

Comment: @Zarko  But the examples give OP some options. Maybe the tables in not for reading, but to archive figures which can be used as evidence for something in the future. SInce OP asks, he has obviously some thoughts regarding what to use it for.

Comment: @Zarko my supervisor insists to add it :(

Comment: thanks a lot everyone for guidance

Comment: @UsamaMudassar If the answer was to any help, please consider accepting it.

Comment: @Sveinung how to accept it ?

Comment: @UsamaMudassar: You can accept Sveinung's answer by clicking on the checkmark ✓ (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852))