# How to link subtables to a tabular

Tags: tables, hyperref

This was intended to be an answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507610/how-to-make-40x50-table-in-latex-such-that-it-is-visible).  OTOH, it might be possible to improve upon it using eforms or better `\href` options.

The idea is to first create a PDF file containing the subtables.

```
\documentclass[multi=subtable]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newenvironment{subtable}[2]% #1 = target name, #2 = tabular columns
{\hypertarget{#1}\bgroup\begin{tabular}{#2}}% body goes here
{\end{tabular}\egroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{subtable}{first}{S|S}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{First}\\
{x} & {y}\\
\hline
1.0 & 3.2\\
1.5 & 2.9
\end{subtable}

\begin{subtable}{second}{S|S}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Second}\\
{x} & {y}\\
\hline
1.0 & 3.2\\
1.5 & 2.9
\end{subtable}

\end{document}
```

Then use `\href` to link this file (test6.pdf) to the main document.  Note the use of `\#` to add the anchors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \belowcaptionskip=\abovecaptionskip
  \abovecaptionskip=0pt
  \caption{Main Table - click entries}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    &\href[pdfnewwindow]{test6.pdf\#first}{First} \\% note {first} is the target name
    \href[pdfnewwindow]{test6.pdf\#second}{Second}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note that each subtable starts up a new PDF viewer, so you can return by closing the page.

Comment: `\#` should not be necessary, simply `#` works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version which puts all the subtables into an appendix, using just `\label` and `\ref`.  Presumably the actual subtables will be bigger and may possibly require a full page each.  The choice of [hp] is because there is no limit on how many [p] floats can go on a page, but also want some on the first page of the section.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{linked}{Subtable \ref{main}#2}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Table goes in main text}
\begin{table}[ht]
  \caption{Main Table}\label{main}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    & See \ref{first}\\
    See \ref{second}&
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\clearpage
\appendix
\section[Subtables for Table \ref*{main}]{Subtables for Table \ref{main}}

\begingroup
  \renewcommand{\thetable}{\ref*{main}}%
  \renewcommand{\thesubtable}{.\arabic{subtable}}%
  \captionsetup[subtable]{labelformat=linked}%
  \setcounter{subtable}{0}% not automatic

\begin{table}[hp]
  \captionof{subtable}{}\label{first}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{S|S}
    {x} & {y}\\
    \hline
    1.0 & 3.2\\
    1.5 & 2.9
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[hp]
  \captionof{subtable}{}\label{second}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{S|S}
{x} & {y}\\
    \hline
    1.0 & 3.2\\
    1.5 & 2.9
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\endgroup% restore table subcaptions
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was not able to get it to work with anchors. Also, `pdfpages` to merge pdf files is not an option as that does not retain links.

Comment: @PeterGrill I do find it quite unclear what the question and your remarks is about. What is missing? The links in the question works fine for me. So what "improvement" is wanted?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Given the code in the question, does clicking on "Second" open the document to Page 2 (the "Second" table) for you?  For me it opens to Page 1 (the "First" table). The answer puts everything into one pdf document, where as the question has the tables in a separate pdf document.

Comment: @PeterGrill yes the code works fine for me.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. The code posted in the question seems to work fine for me now -- not sure what happened earlier when clicking on `second` would open the `first` table.  I think the solution in the question is much better than the answer. :-) I am awarding the bounty to this answer (although it is really for the code given in the question).

Comment: Vielen dank!  Now I can close it.